# Trying to automate yubikey deployment in my workplace

Tags: bash, gpg, yubikey

I am trying to write a basic script that will run the 
gpg --card-edit command on any connected yubikey and generate an RSA 4096 key pair on the card

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`  
set -euf
set -o pipefail

echo "${red}script started${reset}"

echo " ${red}run card edit ${reset}"
gpg --card-edit --command-fd - < ~/bin/yubikey/input2.txt
```

The input2.txt contains the commands I want to run:

```
admin
generate
```

I cannot figure out a way to handle the PIN promt that I get from gpg so I get this error

```
gpg: error checking the PIN: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but perhaps someone, including my future self, will appreciate this... :-)

```
git clone https://github.com/santiago-mooser/yubikey-provisioning-scripts.git
cd yubikey-provisioning-scripts
./yubikey_provision.sh -h
   This script provisions a yubikey by generating a master key, 3 subkeys and moving the subkeys to the yubikey. Please read the documentation for more information.

   Usage: yubikey_provision.sh [-e|--email EMAIL_ADDRESS] [-u|--user-pin USER_PIN] [-a|--admin-pin ADMIN_PIN] [-y|--yes]

   optional arguments:
     -h, --help           show this help message and exit.
     -e, --email          provide email used for PGP key. If it is not provided, the user is prompted for an email.
     -f, --first-name     provide first name used for PGP key. Defaults to an empty string.
     -l, --last-name      provide last name used for PGP key. Defaults to an empty string.
     -c, --comment        provide comment used for PGP key. Defaults to an empty string.
         --username       provide username used for PGP key. Defaults to an empty string.
     -p, --password       provide password used for PGP key. If it is not provided, a random one is generated.
     -u, --user-pin       provide new user pin for the yubikey. If none is provided, a random one is generated.
     -a, --admin-pin      provide new admin pin for the yubikey. If none is provided, a random one is generated.
     -y, --yes            skips prompts to reset the yubikey.
     -v, --version        prints out the version number.
```

This script will help you run all of the other helper scripts in the right order and with the right flags to create a new private key, subkeys, reset the openPGP applet of the connected yubikey and upload the subkeys to the yubikey.

**WARNING**

**The script will also upload your public key to openPGP's public key server! Please disable this in the script if this is not what you want.**

**WARNING**

Read the [**README.md**](https://github.com/santiago-mooser/yubikey-provisioning-scripts) here!

https://github.com/santiago-mooser/yubikey-provisioning-scripts

**WARNING**

**The private key of the yubikey is not exported. If you would like to export your private keys, please uncomment the lines `363-365` of the `yubikey_provision.sh` script**

**Alternatively, to reprovision new subkeys, please create new subkeys as per this official yubikey guide, but select option 14 and continue with the rest of the guide (including moving the subkeys to the yubikey):**

**WARNING**

### Compatibility

This script has been tested with MacOS Monetrrey and Ventura and Ubutuntu 20.04 LTS onwards. It will likely work with earlier versions, but it's not a guarantee.